# android - email address is badly formatted firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

hello I'm making a login in my project and when I try to input the data it says **email address is badly formatted**

*Codes*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email;
private EditText Password;
private ImageButton BackMenu;
private TextView SignIn;
private Button login;

ProgressBar progressBar;

private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.log_email);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    BackMenu = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.returnMenu);
    SignIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_SignIn);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginUser();

        }
    });

    SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registrationForm();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    BackMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openShopMenu();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

private void loginUser() {
    String userEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String userPass = Password.getText().toString().trim();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }
    if (userPass.length() < 5){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password must be 5 characters or more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userPass,userEmail)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login is Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

}

public void openShopMenu() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShopMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void registrationForm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

**Problem**

the input is:

Email : gon@gmail.com

Password : 12345678

The user fails to login and the message below pops out

**The email address is badly formatted**

and I don't think there's a problem in my .xml file

`android:inputType="textEmailAddress"`

Comment: Can you try logging your email right before `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and see if the input is as expected?

Comment: What is the exact value of the email address when you sign in?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yeah the 'Toast' appear before the 'signInWithEmailAndPassword'

Comment: @AlexMamo its string value when i sign in

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: @AlexMamo what do you mean?

Comment: Show us an example of the email you are using. Most likely is "bad formatted", right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes that appear when I try to login and I'm sorry if you want to see a image because I can't sorry